# Need help with Test case for this update trigger.expecting test body only

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test

```
 trigger leadupdatecontact on Lead(after update){
    list<contact> con=new list<contact>();
   for(Lead le :trigger.new){     
         contact co=new contact();       
 if(le.convertedcontactid != NULL&&le.description!= Null&&co.description!=le.description)  {   
        co.description=le.description; 
        co.id=le.convertedcontactid; 
        con.add(co);
       }
     }
 update con;
}
```

this is the i wrote.

```
  @istest(seealldata=true) 
      public class testleadupdatecontact{ 

         static testMethod void testleadupdatecontact(){ 
            contact co=new contact(Lastname='Deep',description=''); 
            insert co; 
            lead l=new lead(Lastname='deep',custom__c=true,company='tejjjjj'); 
            insert l; l.id='00QN00000011W3G'; 
            update l; 
            co.Lastname='Deep'; 
            co.id='003N0000007CLdv'; 
            l.description=co.description; 
            update co; 
            } 
         }
```

i have many possible ways ,but it is not showing the code coverage can any body send me the body of this test case

Comment: hi mohit i wrote one test for this one ,it is showing 83% code coverage in sandbox ,but while deploying in production it is showing that atleast one 1% is required for deploying.why it is not taking that 83% code coverage .do you have any idea

Comment: can you post your test class ?

Comment: @istest(seealldata=true)
public class testleadupdatecontact{
static testMethod void testleadupdatecontact(){
contact co=new contact(Lastname='Deep',description='');
insert co;
lead l=new lead(Lastname='deep',custom__c=true,company='tejjjjj');
insert l;
l.id='00QN00000011W3G';
update l;
 co.Lastname='Deep';
 co.id='003N0000007CLdv';
 l.description=co.description;
 update co;
  } }

Comment: i have edited a lot currently i am having only this code

Comment: what i see is test code is completely wrong written.You will need to convert a lead to existing contact to fire this trigger off .Also hardcoding Id is not good at all.The record may exist in full copy but not in production

Comment: Hard coding in the sense id

Comment: answered the same .Yes the Ids .Also see the below answer .Also i am observing you are not voting or accepting the right answers .

Comment: Any way i am learning one by one,good to better and better to best.Thank you for your valuable suggestions

Answer (score 3):

Obviously for this question i dont see any point in writing the test code myself ,but here is the hint on how to proceed

> A lead has to be converted into the existing contact in test class

```
Test.startTest();

    Database.LeadConvert lc = new database.LeadConvert();
    lc.setLeadId(lead.id);
    lc.setDoNotCreateOpportunity(false); //**IMPORTANT METHOD HERE**
    lc.setAccountId(account.id);
    lc.setContactId(contact.id);

    LeadStatus convertStatus = [SELECT Id, MasterLabel FROM LeadStatus WHERE IsConverted=true LIMIT 1];
    lc.setConvertedStatus(convertStatus.MasterLabel);
    Database.LeadConvertResult lcr = Database.convertLead(lc);

    Test.stopTest();
```

> **Obviously a sample account,contact and lead has to be created and assumed in above testcode ,then description has to be changed for contact and lead as per the business logic of above class.**